# When we set magento 1.9 store the gst include in product but show other tax in order review time

Tags: checkout, place-order

[image]
[image]

When we add GST  in the magento store but the checkout time in the order review include show other tax. The product tax class none  but show tax in Place order
 .

Answer (score 0):

Set product's tax class to **None** from the admin panel. Then that Magento tax will not be applied.
[image]

Comment: Product's tax class  option not show  in which link option  available

Comment: Edit product in admin panel

Comment: Check updated answer. I added screenshot.

Comment: Product  tax class none but show in  order review page Check updated screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Go to **system > configuration > Sales > tax** and you can see various configuration settings for tax and change settings as you required :

[image]

Comment: this setting change product price . I remove  Tax  show only GST

Comment: @gaganbafna so you are telling you included tax in product price only, so you dont want to display any tax for products in checkout page ?

Comment: I include  GST  tax in products  of  store . But  show  other tax  in order review page

Comment: may be some configuration you are missing, because what tax you set for products, that tax only should display in order vew page, may be you are calculation tax for shipping price or better check these links and check configuration : [link1](http://www.harapartners.com/blog/setting-tax-classes-magento-tax-setup/) , [link2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_taxes.htm) and [link3](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/tax/tax-rules.html)